# UWP app with InterstitialAd debugs on device but can't create package for Store

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, ads

I am creating a UWP app that consest of a video ad with InterstitialAd (using Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI;)

When I debug the app with win 10 device, it works well.
and I have no problems with building the app.

But the only one issue is that I can;t create a package in order to upload it to the store.

the following is the output of the file:

```
1>C:\Users\Hatim Makki\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WaitOrLeave\WaitOrLeave\WaitOrLeave.csproj : XamlCompiler error WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.winmd'
1>  WaitOrLeave -> C:\Users\Hatim Makki\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WaitOrLeave\WaitOrLeave\bin\ARM\Release\mopo.exe
1>  Starting .NET Native compilation
1>  Processing application code
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : Internal compiler error: MCG0023:UnresolvableAssemblyReference Unresolvable assembly reference 'Assembly(Name=Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

and finally, these are my references:
[image]

and this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Internal compiler error: MCG0023:UnresolvableAssemblyReference Unresolvable assembly reference 'Assembly(Name=Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime)' found. Please check the references in your build system. A reference is either missing or an assembly is missing an expected type. WaitOrLeave
```

Any help?

thanks

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2015 are you using? We did fix some issues around this scenario in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, so my recommendation would be to use the very latest updated to Visual Studio - Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. If you are already using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and can reproduce this issue, please do share out a project that demonstrates this issue and we can investigate (I could not reproduce the issue).